# Fill div with content from another file using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, svg

I have a for loop that creates divs. I want to put the contents from external SVG files into each div created. So I'm using an AJAX request:

```
for (var i=0; i<12; i++) {
  var newTile = document.createElement('div');

  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) { newTile.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; }
  }
  xmlhttp.open('GET','assets/svg/1001-1001.svg',true);
  xmlhttp.send();

  document.getElementById('myDiv').appendChild(newTile);
}
```

It seems to put the contents in the last div created but not the others. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When does `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` fire? How about if you try  `var newTile = []` so that `newTile[i] = document.createElement('div');` and then `newTile[i].innerHTML =` and so on.

Comment: The AJAX request will run asynchronously so it will not set the innerHTML property until the request has come back from the server. This means that the for loop will have run all 12 before the first value is coming back from the server.

Comment: @daniellepelley thanks that makes sense. Could you suggest an answer with a solution please?

Comment: You could create a closure, so the xmlhttp gets captured for each anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

You should rewrite it to handle asynchronous requests or change the third parameter to false to make it synchronous.

```
xmlhttp.open('GET','assets/svg/1001-1001.svg',false);
```

Asynchronous

```
for (var i=0; i<12; i++) {


  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        var newTile = document.createElement('div');
        newTile.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; 
        document.getElementById('myDiv').appendChild(newTile);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open('GET','assets/svg/1001-1001.svg',true);
  xmlhttp.send();


}
```

Comment: The synchronous method works fine for me, but the asynchronous method doesn't load the SVG in all divs

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    var tiles = [];
    for (var i=0; i<12; i++) {
      tile[i] = document.createElement('div');

      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) { tile[i].innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; }
      }
      xmlhttp.open('GET','assets/svg/1001-1001.svg',true);
      xmlhttp.send();

      document.getElementById('myDiv').appendChild(tile[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think moving all the div creation code into the AJAX return function should fix the issue.

```
for (var i=0; i<12; i++) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        var newTile = document.createElement('div');
        newTile.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        document.getElementById('myDiv').appendChild(newTile); }
    }

    xmlhttp.open('GET','assets/svg/1001-1001.svg',true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to load the svg content into each div for me

Answer (score 0):

That is because the newTile variable is beeing overritten and not beeing redeclared. The variable belongs to the scope of the function the for loop is in. 
This is something that is different in javascript.

try the following

```
for (var i=0; i<12; i++) {
  (function (){
  var newTile = document.createElement('div');

  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) { newTile.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; }
  }
  xmlhttp.open('GET','assets/svg/1001-1001.svg',true);
  xmlhttp.send();

  document.getElementById('myDiv').appendChild(newTile);
  })();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than:

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').appendChild(newTile);
```

Try:

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText
```